# php ajax return false issue

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the following `ajax function`

```
function validatec()
{
    var coupon = jQuery('#validateC').val();
    var data = "coupon="+coupon;

        $.ajax({
            type      : 'POST', //Method type
            url       : 'https://sainicomputers.co.in/exam/index.php/login/test/', //Your form processing file URL
            data      : data, 
            async : false, 
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg > 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please enter a valid Coupon Code");

                }
                 return false; 

            }

        });
}
```

What I want to do is that when the result is received from ajax call then I dont want to load the page. but this code is not working how can I do this ?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've shown that would cause a page refresh.

Comment: I dont want to load page on success

Comment: that's what @Utkanos said that in your code there is nothing that would cause a page refresh. Provide more code please (your html would help)

Answer (score 1):

Your code not showing that there is a cause to page refresh, i think that you are calling the ajax when you click o button of type 'submit',
if yes, you have to change the type from submit to button and in your success reponse you have to add somthing like:

```
jQuery('#form').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, I have made few tweaks.

On a side note: I think that `return false;` before the `success` function closes might also be a potential issue.

```
function validatec()
{
    var couponCode = jQuery('#validateC').val();
    var dataString = {coupon:couponCode} //change over here

        $.ajax({
            method    : 'POST', //change over here
            url       : 'https://sainicomputers.co.in/exam/index.php/login/test/', //Your form processing file URL
            data      : dataString, 
            async     : false, 
            success   : function(msg) {
                alert("Enter success") //change over here
                if(msg > 0)
                {
                    alert("Coupon Valid"); //change over here
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please enter a valid Coupon Code");
                    return false; //change over here
                }
                alert("Exit success")  //change over here

            }

        });
}
```